# Inserting a string value and formatted string into table using the same insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a homework problem that states this:

> Populate the tables with data, ensuring that there are at least 5 people, at least 8 posts, and at least 4 likes. Make sure to use sequences to generate the primary key values. Most of the fields are self-explanatory. As far as the “content” field in Post, make them whatever you like, such as “Take a look at these new pics” or “Just arrived in the Bahamas”, and set the summary as the first 12 characters of the content, followed by “…”.

For this problem, I have a table called Post:

```
CREATE TABLE Post
(
    post_id decimal(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , person_id decimal(12) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(person_id)
    , content varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , created_on date NOT NULL
    , summary varchar(15) NOT NULL 
)
```

For this homework problem, I am trying to find out how to solve a problem: "set the summary as the first 12 characters of the content, followed by “…”.". Basically, I am trying to write content on the summary field by taking the first 12 characters

And I have this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, 'Take a look at these new pics', GETDATE(), SUBSTRING('Take a look at these new pics', 1, 12) + '...')
```

and I tried this to avoid repeatability

```
INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, 'Take a look at these new pics', GETDATE(), SUBSTRING(content, 1, 12) + '...')
```

However this insert statement would not work because it does not know what the content is. What would be the best way to apply formatting on the same value that I am inserting, without having to write it again in the same insert statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use a variable for this (and in fact all of your insert parameters which come from the user):

```
DECLARE @Content varchar(255) = 'Take a look at these new pics';

INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, @Content, GETDATE(), SUBSTRING(@Content, 1, 12) + '...');
```

And for bonus points, don't add the `...` unless some concatenation takes place e.g.

```
DECLARE @Content varchar(255) = 'Take a look at these new pics';

INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, @Content, GETDATE(), SUBSTRING(@Content, 1, 12) + CASE WHEN LEN(@Content) > 12 then '...' else '' end);
```

Or use a sub-query e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, X.content, GETDATE()
        , SUBSTRING(X.content, 1, 12) + CASE WHEN LEN(X.content) > 12 then '...' else '' end
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Take a look at these new pics' as content
    ) X;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to do two queries.

```
INSERT INTO Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on)
VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, 'Take a look at these new pics', GETDATE());

UPDATE Post SET summary = SUBSTRING(content, 1, 12) + '...';
```

That UPDATE will do all the records.  If your SQL database has a "record id of last record", you could use that to limit the UPDATE to the one you just added.